# getting module has no attribute error after compiling with f2py

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, f2py

I have ran into a problem, while trying to make a bunch of Fortran code work in Python using f2py (in gfortran). My Fortran code has a whole bunch of subroutines and it compiles fine both in gfortran and an online virtual fortran IDE.
The subroutine I'm having issues with is a mergesort subroutine (which I took from rosettastone and modified), it looks like this:

```
subroutine MSort(N, A, A_out)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: N 
    real, dimension(N), intent(in) :: A
    real, dimension(N), intent(out) :: A_out
    real :: work((size(A) + 1) / 2)
    A_out=A
    call MergeSort(A_out, work)
  contains

  subroutine merge(A, B, C)
    implicit none
    real, target, intent(in) :: A(:), B(:)
    real, target, intent(inout) :: C(:)
    integer :: i, j, k

    if (size(A) + size(B) > size(C)) then
        stop
    end if
    i = 1; j = 1
    do k = 1, size(C)
      if (i <= size(A) .and. j <= size(B)) then
        if (A(i) <= B(j)) then
          C(k) = A(i)
          i = i + 1
        else
          C(k) = B(j)
          j = j + 1
        end if
      else if (i <= size(A)) then
        C(k) = A(i)
        i = i + 1
      else if (j <= size(B)) then
        C(k) = B(j)
        j = j + 1
      end if
    end do
  end subroutine merge

  subroutine swap(x, y)
    implicit none
    real, intent(inout) :: x, y
    real :: tmp
    tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp
  end subroutine

  recursive subroutine MergeSort(A, work)
    implicit none
    real, intent(inout) :: A(:)
    real, intent(inout) :: work(:)
    integer :: half
    half = (size(A) + 1) / 2
    if (size(A) < 2) then
      continue
    else if (size(A) == 2) then
      if (A(1) > A(2)) then
        call swap(A(1), A(2))
      end if
    else
      call MergeSort(A( : half), work)
      call MergeSort(A(half + 1 :), work)
      if (A(half) > A(half + 1)) then
        work(1 : half) = A(1 : half)
        call merge(work(1 : half), A(half + 1:), A)
      endif
    end if
  end subroutine MergeSort
end subroutine MSort
```

I compiled it with

```sh
$ f2py -c -m fprogram fprogram.f90
```

and inserted `import fprogram` in the beginning of my python code (in a jupyter notebook), where I wanted to use it like this (I know original is a list, it's not dimensional issues):

```py
size=len(original_list)
sorted_list=fprogram.MSort(size,original_list)
```

I got the error message

```sh
module 'fprogram' has no attribute 'MSort'
```

Meanwhile, when I used any other subroutine from fprogram in the same way it works perfectly.
I already modified the fortran code to not have variables with `intent(inout)` because in a previous case this has solved my problem, but it didn't work this time. What I can I do to make python recognze this subroutine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different errors.

At first, `f2py` creates all lowercase procedures.
Thus, you need to call `fprogram.msort` which is exactly what the error message tries to tell you.

On the other hand, `f2py` figured out that the argument `N` is redundant in python.
Which is why it created a function where `N` is an optional paramenter.
Thus, you also need to call it in one of the following ways

```py
sorted_list=fprogram.msort(original_list)
sorted_list=fprogram.msort(original_list, size)
sorted_list=fprogram.msort(original_list, n=size)
```

---

How did I find that out?
I read the documentation by calling (in the python REPL)

```py
import fprogram
help(fprogram)
```